# UPDATE NO MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho um campo criptografado, no banco de dados MYSQL.
estou tentando dar update dessa maneira

```
UPDATE USUARIOS
SET SENHA = md5(1234)
WHERE ID = 216;
```

mas me da essa mensagem de erro:

> Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'SENHA' at rom 1

Comment: Qual o script de criação da tabela USUARIOS?

Comment: O número de caracteres retornado pelo `md5()` deve ter estourado o limite de `senha`

Comment: a coluna senha é varchar(20)

Comment: Md5 não gera um hash de 32 chars ?

Comment: Entao como que ele criptografa, se só possui 20 espaços?

Comment: Por isso o erro de "data too long". Aumente para 32 e teste

Comment: Conta lá quantos caracteres há em `$SENHA` https://ideone.com/7Xx0D1

Comment: Eu aumentei para varchar(100) e ele muda, mas na hora de eu fazer o loguin, nao reconhece

Comment: e como  você está fazendo o loguin? `...where senha= ????`

Comment: Tenha certeza que está comparando md5 com md5, não senha com md5.

Comment: $senha = MD5($_POST['senha']);

Comment: Ai eu tenho que vê com o cara que tem o codigo fonte, pois nao altero ele.
Faço somente alterações no banco

Answer (score 0):

Sem o script da criação da tabela não há como saber a quantidade de caracteres que a coluna "senha" suporta, mas o erro indica que o valor que tá sendo atribuído ao campo tem uma quantidade de caracteres maior do que o que ele aceita. Dá uma verificada em quantos caracteres a sua hash está gerando e, se for o caso, aumente a quantidade de caracteres do campo pra ele poder armazenar o valor retornado.

Comment: Eu aumentei para varchar(100) e ele muda, mas na hora de eu fazer o loguin, nao reconhece

Comment: Mas e o update? Funcionou e parou de dar o erro que foi perguntado?

Comment: o Update funcionou, so que a senha nao foi alterada para oque eu coloquei

Comment: Tem como postar um exemplo melhor disso?

Comment: Ai eu tenho que vê com o cara que tem o codigo fonte, pois nao altero ele. Faço somente alterações no banco

Comment: Compreendo. Se minha resposta te ajudou fico feliz, e quando conseguir o fonte sobre o outro problema o publique em uma nova pergunta.